# Вытащить несколько чисел из строки?

Tags: php, php7

Как из строки вытащить числа массива?

Comment: Дак это и есть массив, а не строка.

Comment: нет это строку она приходит в таком виде из базы данных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = '["777","888","999"]';

preg_match_all('~\d+~', $str, $arr);
$arr = $arr[0];

print_r($arr);
```

---

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 777
    [1] => 888
    [2] => 999
)
```

Comment: у меня строка в другом формате на ней не проходит  ["777","888","999"]

Comment: @Ivan912 дак в чём проблема? Опубликуйте строку в вашем вопросе.

Comment: добавил строку в вопрос

Comment: @Ivan912, вы не строку добавили, а массив. И в таком случае, вам ничего больше делать не нужно

Answer (score 4):

```
$str = '["777","888","999"]';
print_r(json_decode($str, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$str = '["777","888","999"]';

$decode = json_decode($str, true);

print_r($decode);
```

Результат:

```
Array ( [0] => 777 [1] => 888 [2] => 999 )
```